# iOS Unit Testing Bundle: Why Is The App Launched?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode9, xctest

I have added a Unit Test target and a UI Test target to my application project. When I run the Unit Tests my application is launched. When I run the UI Tests a "special Runner version" of my application is launched. I (barely) understand that the runner version is for producing user actions. But why is my app launched when the unit tests are run? The implication is that my unit tests can interact with the running application but that does not seem to be the case. The whole XCTest environment is new to me. Any clarifications would be just great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. It indeed is possible for a unit test to access the running application. I added the following test method and it successfully printed the list and map view controller properties of my application's page view controller:

```
    func testAppAccess() {
        if let pageVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0] as? PageViewController {
            print(pageVC.listViewController)
            print(pageVC.mapViewController)
        }
        else { print("Could not obtain the application's page view controller") }
    }
```